# If my world has silver instead of Tungsten, can I still make an Emerald Staff?

Tags: terraria

The recipe for Emerald Staff says I need Tungsten. Isn't silver supposed to be interchangeable with tungsten? Why should I have to re-make my world just to get a metal...

Comment: Neither the linked question, nor the answer given give the full details. While you can't make an Emerald Staff, with Silver, you can make a Sapphire Staff which is the same. In my world (first time playing as of 1.2) the Sapphire Staff is functionally the same as the Emerald Staff.

Comment: You don't *have* to re-gen your world, that staff is not the most important thing in Terraria.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is possible, only downside is that you can't naturally find the silver, you have to obtain it via the Extractinator.

The Extractinator turns Silt/Slush into ores and gems. There is an 8.1% chance that it will give you silver. You can find it as a rare drop in underground gold chests.

http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Extractinator

Comment: Thanks, also I could always try a new world and then go back to my old one.

Comment: That's also an option. But I wouldn't recommend it since you'll be constantly wasting your time by traveling between worlds. Besides, there is A LOT of silt to collect after you've dug deep enough to reach the Caverns.